# How to store complex number in a character array in c++ without using std::string, nor any STL?

Tags: c++

I am looking to take 2 integers as input from user say 5 and 6 and need to store it as a complex number i.e. 5 + i6 in a character array. Condition is that I cannot use the string and ccomplex libraries.

I am not looking to print it as in not looking to do something like this:

```
char x= 5+'/0';
char y= 6+'/0';
cout<< x << " i"<<y;
```

But rather something which would be equivalent to this:

```
char x[10]= "5 +i6";
```

Comment: Are you allowed to make your own class, and use that?

Comment: yes I can do that.

Comment: Then you could make a class that stores the values as member data, and constructs an array from that.  Or something that just reads in integers, and constructs an array from them.

Comment: I actually intend to do that but struggling to construct an array from data members

Comment: Ah.  Are you allowed to use members of the standard library, as long as they're not part of the standard template library?  Because if you are, `snprintf()` is what you want, like Benoît said in the answers.  Instead of printing to standard output, it prints to the first parameter, which is a `char*` (including `char` array).

Comment: yup, snprintf() seems to be the easiest way out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use std::string. So the question is why, and how does whoever set the problem want string data passed about? It's perfectly reasonable not to allow std::strings, but do you have your own class, do you use C strings with fixed buffers provide by caller, or do you pass about C strings allocated with malloc(). There are also other possible alternatives.

If you've got your own string class, we can't answer without seeing it. To fill in a C buffer provide by caller

```
/* return 0 on success, -1 if buffer too small */
int toString(char *buff, int N, int real, int imaginary)
{
   int sz = snprintf(buff, N, "%d + %di", real, iamginary);
   if(sz > N-1)
     return -1;
   return 0;
}
```

To pass about strings allocated with malloc.

```
/* return a string allocated with malloc */
char *toString(int real, int imaginary)
{
   int sz;
   char *answer = 0;
   const char *fmt = "%d + %di";

   sz = snprintf(0, 0, fmt, real, imaginary);
   answer = malloc(sz + 1);
   if(answer)
     snprintf("answer, sz+1, fmt, real, imaginary); 

   return answer;   
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation!

Answer (score 3):

If you cannot use string, then you cannot use std::stringstream i guess. So fallback to `snprintf(buf, sizeof buf, "%d + i%d", 5, 6)`.

Comment: Thanks! quite simple once you know something like this exists